# How to manage video frames in memory

Tags: java, android, memory, video, frames

My app is grabbing all the frames of a video with FFMPEG.
My problem is, where do i save all the frames?
I already tried to convert the frames to bitmap and save to an arraylist, but the app says out of Memory.
Also, when i save the IplImages to an arraylist(it runs) but takes more than 500 MB.
I used a video with low quality. Those with high quality doesn't run neither with the IplImages.

Comment: Are you aware to the FFmpeg's licence? it's GPL, meaning that if you are using it in your app then your app's licence must be also GPL and hence - open source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can't load all of these frames in memory becouse there is a memory limit. To check the limit you can google Android heap size, it's different for each device but it's not that much. You'll have to process it frame by frame and save it on a storage device like the sdcard.

Comment: But if the app read and save, at the same time, on sdcard frame by frame, will be too slow just to upload the video right?

Comment: but maybe it's better than have the app consuming a lot of ram.